# AngularJs ng-show = true, but class ng-hide is added

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I have the following .html code and .js code:

waitCursor.html:

```
<div ng-show="show">
    <div class="text-center">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Loading...
    </div>
</div>
```

simpleControls.js:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("simpleControls", [])
        .directive("waitCursor", waitCursor);

    function waitCursor() {
        alert("aaaa");
        return {
            templateUrl: "/views/waitCursor.html"
        };
    }

})();
```

app-trips.js:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    alert("bbb");
    angular.module("app-trips", ["simpleControls"]);
})();
```

And in my .cshtml file I am calling:

```
<wait-cursor ng-show="true" > </wait-cursor>
```

But eventhough I have all the components set to true, the  still gets `class="ng-hide"`
P.S. alerts are there just to make sure the Angular is working.

Also adding a picture: [Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOglF.png)

Comment: `return {
           scope: { show: true },
            templateUrl: "/views/waitCursor.html"
        };` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ng-show="true"` on the level of directive has nothing to do with `ng-show` on the level of `div` in your directive. If you want to use bounded variable you need to define it in scope of directive and then use it in your directive:

```
{
   scope: {
     ngShowOutsdieDirective: '=ngShowFromInside'
   }
}
```

from https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

P.S: not sure if you can use binding to standard ng-show. You can try `ngShow: '=show'` and then in your html of directive:

```
<div ng-show="show">
    <div class="text-center">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Loading...
    </div>
</div>
```